# crear un un aviso de errores con wp_login_form()

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

os contacto por que ando bastante bloqueado con este problema:

```
<?php
            if (!is_user_logged_in()) { // Display WordPress login form:

                $args = array(
                    'echo'    => true,
                    'form_id' => 'loginform2',
                    'label_log_in' => __('Login'),
                    'label_username' => __(''),
                    'label_password' => __(''),
                    'id_username' => 'account1',
                    'id_password' => 'password1',
                    'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
                    'id_submit' => 'login1',
                    'remember' => false,
                );
                if ($registered) {
                    $args['value_username'] = $user_login->user_login;
                }
                wp_login_form($args);
            } else {
                wp_loginout(home_url()); // Display "Log Out" link.
                echo " | ";
                wp_register('', ''); // Display "Site Admin" link.
            }
            ?>
```

Que me retorna esto:

```
<form name="loginform2" id="loginform2" action="/wp-login.php" method="post" class="bebas">

        <p class="login-username">
            <label for="account1"></label>
            <input type="text" name="log" id="account1" class="input" value="" size="20" placeholder="E-MAIL">
        </p>
        <p class="login-password">
            <label for="password1"></label>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="password1" class="input" value="" size="20" placeholder="PASSWORT">
        </p>


        <p class="login-submit">
            <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="login1" class="button button-primary" value="Login">
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="/login/">
        </p>

    </form>
```

En principio hace su trabajo, me puedo loguear, me redirige, todo ok.
El problema es que si ingreso un mail que no esta en la base de datos, o dejo cualquiera de los campos vacíos. No retorna ningún error, lo que hace es que me redirige a la pantalla de login de wordpress y ahí me muestra los fallos. Y eso es lo que yo no quiero que pase.

He intentado con hacerlo con AJAX des esta manera:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#login1").click(function () {
                    $('#message').hide().html('');
                    var input_data = $('#loginform2').serialize(),
                        logUser = $('#account1').val(),
                        logPass = $('#password1').val();

                    if (logUser == '' && logPass != '') {
                        $('#message').show().html('<p>Your Username is empty!</p>');
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (logPass == '' && logUser != '') {
                        $('#message').show().html('<p>Your Password is empty!</p>');
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (logUser == '' && logPass == '') {
                        $('#message').show().html('<p>Your Username and Password is empty!</p>');
                        return false;
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo site_url('/wp-login.php'); ?>",
                        data: input_data,
                        success: function (msg) {

                            $(location).attr('href', '<?php echo home_url(); ?>');

                        },
                        error: function (msg) {

                            $('#message').show();
                            $('#message').html("<?php _e('<p>Your login  is not correct. Please try again.</p>'); ?>");
                        }

                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

Pero funciona hasta que tiene que validad en la base de datos si el mail existe o no. Cosa que no hace y ya no se que hacer.
**Alguien puede darme una idea de que puede estar fallando aquí?**

Comment: Si lo que quieres es validar si un mail existe haz una llamada ajax que retorne si existe o no

Comment: El problema es que eso es lo que no se hacer. Llevo aprendiendo AJAX una semana como mucho, y estoy bloqueado con esoto.